# ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

So I was attempting to upgrade my RN from 0.61.5 -> 0.64.2.

When attempting to run `react-native run-ios` I was presented with this error

`lang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

My Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
use_frameworks!

platform :ios, '10.0'

target '{MY_APP_NAME_HERE}' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  target '{MY_APP_NAME_HERE}Tests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end
  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
        end
    end
  end

  $static_framework = ['FlipperKit', 'Flipper', 'Flipper-Folly',
    'CocoaAsyncSocket', 'ComponentKit', 'DoubleConversion',
    'glog', 'Flipper-PeerTalk', 'Flipper-RSocket', 'Yoga', 'YogaKit',
    'CocoaLibEvent', 'OpenSSL-Universal', 'boost-for-react-native']

  pre_install do |installer|
    Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
    installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
        if $static_framework.include?(pod.name)
          def pod.build_type;
            Pod::BuildType.static_library
          end
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Tried:

1. building it from xCode with .xcworkspace
2. deleting node_modules -> `yarn install`
3. deleting /Pods and podfile.lock -> `pod install`

Any help would be appreciated

xCode : 12.4